# tcpdump -dd output doesn't match pcap_compile_nopcap

Tags: linux, pcap, libpcap, packet-capture

When I create a packet filter (eg for only tcp traffic) with

```
tcpdump -dd tcp
```

the packet filter output is

```
{ 0x28, 0, 0, 0x0000000c },
{ 0x15, 0, 2, 0x000086dd },
{ 0x30, 0, 0, 0x00000014 },
{ 0x15, 3, 4, 0x00000006 },
{ 0x15, 0, 3, 0x00000800 },
{ 0x30, 0, 0, 0x00000017 },
{ 0x15, 0, 1, 0x00000006 },
{ 0x6, 0, 0, 0x0000ffff },
{ 0x6, 0, 0, 0x00000000 },
```

But when I do the same programatically;

```
pcap_compile_nopcap(1500, DLT_EN10MB, &fcode, "tcp", 1, 0);
struct bpf_insn *insn = fcode.bf_insns;

for (i = 0; i < fcode.bf_len; ++insn, ++i)
{
  printf("{ 0x%x, %d, %d, 0x%08x },\n",
     insn->code, insn->jt, insn->jf, insn->k);
}
```

I get the following packet filter output:

```
{ 0x28, 0, 0, 0x0000000c },
{ 0x15, 0, 5, 0x000086dd },
{ 0x30, 0, 0, 0x00000014 },
{ 0x15, 6, 0, 0x00000006 },
{ 0x15, 0, 6, 0x0000002c },
{ 0x30, 0, 0, 0x00000036 },
{ 0x15, 3, 4, 0x00000006 },
{ 0x15, 0, 3, 0x00000800 },
{ 0x30, 0, 0, 0x00000017 },
{ 0x15, 0, 1, 0x00000006 },
{ 0x6, 0, 0, 0x000005dc },
{ 0x6, 0, 0, 0x00000000 },
```

Why are the two packet filters different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because the tcpdump on your system is built with an older version of libpcap than your program.  The tcpdump on your system is probably using a libpcap without this change:

```
commit 58275c05a5cf9c3512bcbb1192ff351d32ccccbd
Author: Guy Harris <guy@alum.mit.edu>
Date:   Thu Sep 1 22:21:45 2011 -0700

    Handle some amount of IPv6 fragmentation.

    If we're checking for a particular protocol running on top of IPv6, and
    we're not doing full protocol-chain chasing for all "running on top of
    IPv6" tests, at least check for a fragmentation header before the header
    for the protocol.
```

and your program is probably using a libpcap with that change.  That change went into libpcap somewhere in the libpcap 1.3.x timeframe.

Comment: hhmm, tcpdump --version shows "libpcap version 1.1.1" and my debian software centre shows libcap0.8 Version 1.1.1-2squeeze (libcap0.8) installed. Not sure what the 0.8 refers to, but I do believe they are using the same libcap versions...

Comment: The "0.8" refers to the version of libpcap with which they claim binary compatibility, I think.  libpcap releases from tcpdump.org try to preserve binary compatibility, so it should actually be compatible with every release all the way back to the last LBL release, 0.4.

Comment: If, in your program, you call `pcap_lib_version()`, and print the string that it returns, what value does it print?  If it's not version 1.1.1, then you're using a different version of libpcap than the one tcpdump is using.

Comment: Hi
Thanks, it the string returned from pcap_lib_version is "libcap version 1.3.0", so it is indeed different. I almost want to just verify with tcpdump using libcap 1.3.0, but I'll only do that if I have time.

Comment: OK, so the change in question is probably in 1.3.0 (I was too lazy to dig through the libpcap 1.3.x releases to see when it went in).  I'm 99.999999% sure that tcpdump using 1.3.0 will give the same results as your program, so it's probably not worth taking the time to verify it.